# Why can I not instantiate a new Class object?

Tags: java, spring-boot, class, variable-declaration

So this is a real head-scratcher: I've got some code that tests for certain conditions to be met; and when met creates a new Object then sets some values for that Object then adds that Object to a PriorityQueue for further processing later. The code looks something like this:

```
...
import com.example.Position; //Class is properly imported here
...

@Service
public class TradeService extends Thread {
    private final Agent uAgentAcct = new Agent();
    private final HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
    private final Clock clock = new Clock(httpClient);
    private final Authenticator auth = new Authenticator(clock.getServerTime());
    private final MessageConverterFactory parseMsg = new MessageConverterFactory();
    public static ArrayList<Asset> watchList = new ArrayList<Asset>();
    private Position activePosition;
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        [redacted]
    }
    
    private static Position entryScan(ArrayList<Asset> tips) {
        PriorityQueue<Position> posQ = new PriorityQueue<Position>(new PositionComparator());
        for(int i = 0; i < tips.size(); i++) {
            Asset token = tips.get(i); //Instantiating a new Asset instance works just fine right here...
            ArrayList<Candle> chart = token.getChart();
            if(chart.size() >= 14) {
                [redacted]
                if(downTrend && reversion && rsi < 10 && current.getClose() > last.getHigh()) {
                     Position long = new Position(); //But I can't instantiate a new Position instance here? This gets an error from the compiler that states: Position cannot be resolved to a variable
                }
            }
        }
```

As highlighted above, I have a class named "Position" that is imported into this class; however when trying to create a new instance of this class within the if block of my private static entryScan method, the compiler acts as if it has no idea what class I'm referencing, which makes absolutely no sense to me. The only quick fix options I'm given(I'm using Spring Boot, btw) are to create a field "Position", create a local variable "Position", or create a parameter "Position"; none of which I want or need to do. Normally I would expect an option to import the class; but since it already has been imported I'm not sure why the compiler isn't recognizing it. It's almost as if its trying to read my variable type declaration as a field value of TradeService, which is way off base from what I'm actually referencing. So I guess my question is why is it behaving this way and how do I force it to "see" the Position class as a class, and not a field value?

Comment: `long` is a reserved word in Java, referring to the 64bit integer type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a reserved keyword `long` for your variable name. Change it to something else e.g. `Position position = new Position();`

Comment: Of course, how did I not catch that! Thanks so much for your help.